# Mysql: How do I select a if a bit on a specific place is 1?

Tags: sql, select, binary, decimal

I have a mysql column with an integer containing info about the by a user selected options.

Now, for example, the number 42 = 2 + 8 + 32 = 2^**1** + 2^**3** + 2^**5**, so a user with options = 42 has option 1,3 and 5 selected.

How do I select all the users with (at least) option 5 selected? What would be a correct working sql query?

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE ???(`options`) = ???(5);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF `options` is an integer type, you can select the rows with *at least* bit 5 set in their options like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `options` >= POW(2, 5)
```

To select *only* columns with bit 5 set in their options, do

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`options` & POW(2, 5))
```

Comment: Thanx a lot! The second one was the solution I needed. I meant that option 5 is selected and possibly other options as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try bitwise operations:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html

in your code (MySql) the condition could be

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `users` 
 WHERE (`options` & (1 << 5)) <> 0
```